# Postgres Connection Issue Using Docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, nest

Im facing a problem while connecting my nest js and postgres application via docker. Im getting database connection error. I want if my db doesnt exist it should be created automatically when i run docker compose up. Following are my files.

Dockerfile

`
FROM node:16

```
# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json to /app/
COPY package*.json .

# Install npm packages for development
RUN npm install

# Install ts-node globally
RUN npm install -g ts-node

# Copy the rest of the application code to /app/
COPY . .

# Run your database migrations
# RUN npm run migration:run

# Expose port for the development server if needed
EXPOSE 3002

# Start the development server
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start:dev" ]
```

Docker Compose File

```
# based off compose-sample-2, only we build nginx.conf into image
# uses sample HTML static site from https://startbootstrap.com/themes/agency/
version: '3'
services:
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile  # Use the development Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - '.env'
    # command: npm run migration:run && npm run start:dev
    volumes:
      - .:/app  # Mount the same directory as the production web service
    ports:
      - '3002:3002' 
    depends_on:
      - postgres
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: boilerplate  # Change 'mydatabase' to the desired database name
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres   # Change 'myuser' to the desired username
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    ports:
      - '5431:5432'
    volumes:
      # - boilerplate:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
# volumes:
#   boilerplate:
```

```
ENV Variables
DATABASE_HOST=postgres
POSTGRES_DB=boilerplate
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres     DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@postgres:5431/boilerplate
DATABASE_PORT=5431
```

I have tried multiple things but couldnt find any solution to it

Comment: Connections between containers don't use `ports:` at all.  Does changing `DATABASE_PORT` to the standard PostgreSQL port 5432 help?  What's the actual problem you're running into?

Comment: Im facing connection issue basically while running docker compose up.Unable to connect to database

Comment: mern-interview-backend-postgresDB-1  | 2023-09-15 06:47:31.287 UTC [80] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
mern-interview-backend-postgresDB-1  | 2023-09-15 06:47:31.287 UTC [80] DETAIL:  Password does not match for user "postgres".
mern-interview-backend-postgresDB-1  |  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 99: "host all all all md5"


due to it getting unable to connect to database. I have also tried deleting all containers images volumes and building the container again but same error

Answer (score 0):

Try to set an environment variable for the Postgres container, like so:

```
POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
```

This allows you to make a connection without using a password. That will at least allow you to test if your NodeJS app cannot actually reach the Postgres database, or if it's an authorization issue (should obviously be removed once you've solved the problem).

Also, if you only intend to access the database to other containers, use **expose** instead of **port**. That ensures that the database port is not freely accessible from outside the Docker deployment.

Comment: I have added this it allows me to run my backend but if i wanted to run mi migrations in that case i get error
22.92 Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND postgres
22.92     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:109:26) {
where as in Docker file i have added this line RUN npm run migration:run

and other setting are same in my postgres code i shared above

Comment: It sounds like something in the setup is not aligned. Can you paste in your migration:run command from package.json? Are you using some kind of ORM to access the Postgres database?

Comment: Btw, given that it worked without password usage, are you sure that you have tried deleting the volumes? From the Docker Hub image documentation: "Warning: the Docker specific variables will only have an effect if you start the container with a data directory that is empty; any pre-existing database will be left untouched on container startup." - so maybe delete the volumes and ensure that the directories you are mounting are empty?